# How can I add condition in array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

My case like this

My code :

```
if($cover == 'on') 
    $photo = $image;

$this->product_repository->update($id, [
    'photo'     =>$photo,
    'photo_list'=>json_encode($photo_list)
]);
```

I want to add condition in array

If `$cover != on` then it not run this `'photo' => $photo`

Seems it need to add conditon in array

How can I do it?

Comment: Do I understood correctly, that depending on `$cover` value you want to call update with either `photo` and `photo_list` or just with the `photo_list`? Prepare the array in separate variable adding elements as required, then pass it as a parameter to `update` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create array with info for update and add `photo` key in condition:

```
$updateData = [
    'photo_list' => json_encode($photo_list)
];

if($cover == 'on'){
    $updateData['photo'] = $image;
}

$this->product_repository->update($id, $updateData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If photo is nullable you could do this:

```
$this->product_repository->update($id, [
    'photo'     => ($cover == 'on') ? $photo : null,
    'photo_list'=>json_encode($photo_list)
]);
```

Comment: If $cover != on, you answer will update photo field to be null. What I mean is $cover != on, it not update photo field

Comment: @samueltoh oh sure, you don't want to lose existing data. In that case I would go with Andrey's answer.